# Strip on side of window letting cold air in

Tags: insulation

My apartment bedroom window has a thin vertical strip along the right side that allows warm air from the room to escape. Even with the bedroom thermostat set to 80 degrees, the room hasn't gone above 70, mostly due to this.

You can clearly hear that it is not sealed, it sounds as if the window is open an inch or two, but it is actually closed and locked.

How can I seal this strip to prevent warm air from leaking out? It is a plastic material.

[image]

Comment: I'd apply shrink-wrap film to the whole thing, which would also boost the window's insulating value. Available at most hardware stores, or websearch "window shrink film".

Answer (score 1):

If you rent you can always ask the apartment manger the reason for the vent and if it can be closed.  Also look on the side of the window to see if there is any switches, levers or slides to open/close it.  If you don't own, you can always just cover it with 2 inch wide masking tape which will drastically cut down on the airflow and be easy enough to remove at the end of the lease.